# Horizontal slide show

Tags: jquery

I have done a header with jquery which will change the image automatically after some particular time. That's works fine, now I would like to make on this header a horizontal slide which will show the images on a smaller scale where the uaser can skip and navigate through the images.

Any simple suggestions of how I can do this in a simple way in jquery?

Comment: depends on how much you know JS and a library like jQuery. I say this cause it's terribly easy to build something like- your own. But, as I can see this question, I believe you'd be much comfortable with a plugin. And please be more specific if you don't won't to see your question downvoted.

Comment: do you want to use jquery plugins?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use one jquery plugin I recomend you to use:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/automatic-infinite-carousel/

or

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

and here you have many more:

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-image-slider.html

good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

put each image in a `div` with padding and float:left. Using jQuery, wrap them all with a container that is big enough to fit all of them and is positioned absolutely within another `div` with position relative, overflow hidden and fixed width. You're then free to move the container around

HTML structure:

```
<div id="outercontainer" style="width: 500px;overflow: hidden; position:relative;">
  <div id="innercontainer" style="width: *set with jQuery*; position:absolute;top: 0; left: 0">
    <div class="imgContainer" style="padding:20px;float:left">
      <img src="1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer" style="padding:20px;float:left">
      <img src="2.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'set with jquery'in the second line?

Comment: use jQuery to discover the total width of the `imgContainer`s and assign that to the `innercontainer`